# Self referenced column in update

Tags: oracle, triggers

I want to modify the info from a table with articles when a customer makes an order, i mean, when a row is inserted in the table PEDIDO_ARTICULO the info with the number of products remaining should be reduced. I thought in a trigger with an update statement of the table ARTICULOS, it looks like this:

```
--Actualizamos las unidades disponibles del articulo
UPDATE ARTICULO A
SET A.UnidadesDisp = A.UnidadesDisp - v_unidades_pedidas + v_unidades_devueltas
WHERE A.Color= :NEW.Color AND A.Talla=:NEW.Talla AND A.CodigoP=:NEW.CodigoP;
```

Is it possible to self reference UnidadesDisp like that?

Comment: Yes, that's fine; are you getting an error or behaviour that makes you think it is not?